# jq format when running from a bash script with variable expansion

Tags: bash, shell, jq

I've got a jq command that works when running directly from the shell or from within a shell script, but when I try to add variable expansion, I get jq errors for unexpected format or invalid characters. My goal is to have a quick and easy way to update some json configuration.

Here's a simplified example.

The format of the json I'm modifying:

```
{
  "pets": {
      "some-new-pet": {
          "PetInfo": {
             "name": "my-brand-new-pet",
             "toys": [
                 "toy1-postfix",
                 "toy2-postfix",
                 "toy3-postfix"
              ]
          }
      }  
   }
}
```

The jq without variable expansion:

```
cat myfile.json | jq '.pets."some-new-pet" += {PetInfo: {name: "my-brand-new-pet"}, toys: ["toy1", "toy2", "toy3"]}}'
```

The above runs fine, and adds the new `pets.some-new-pet` entry to my json.

Below is what I'm trying to do with variable expansion that fails.

```
jq_args = "'.pets.\"${PET}\" += {PetInfo: {name: \"${NAME}\"}, toys: [\"${toy1}-postfix\", \"${toy2}-postfix\", \"${toy3}-postfix\"]}}'"
cat myfile.json | jq $jq_args
```

The error message I get with the above:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: '.pets."some-new-pet"
```

My file is formatted as utf-8 and uses LF line endings.

Comment: I get the same error even with your "working" command, there is an extra `}` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not recommend constructing a `jq` filter using variable expansion or `printf`. It will work for simple cases but will fail if the string contains double quotes, backslashes or control-codes, as they have special meanings inside a JSON string. As an alternative to using `printf`, `jq` has a way to pass in variables directly via the command-line, avoiding all these issues.

```
pet='some-second-pet'
name='my-even-newer'
toy1=toy1
toy2=toy2
toy3=toy3
jq \
    --arg pet "$pet" \
    --arg name "$name" \
    --arg toy1 "$toy1" \
    --arg toy2 "$toy2" \
    --arg toy3 "$toy3" \
    '.pets[$pet] += {
        PetInfo: {name: $name},
        toys: ["\($toy1)-postfix", "\($toy2)-postfix", "\($toy3)-postfix"]
    }' \
    myfile.json
```

Output:

```
{
  "pets": {
    "some-new-pet": {
      "PetInfo": {
        "name": "my-brand-new-pet",
        "toys": [
          "toy1-postfix",
          "toy2-postfix",
          "toy3-postfix"
        ]
      }
    },
    "some-second-pet": {
      "PetInfo": {
        "name": "my-even-newer-pet"
      },
      "toys": [
        "toy1-postfix",
        "toy2-postfix",
        "toy3-postfix"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have an unknown number of variables to include, consider using  jq's `--args` parameter

Comment: Wow this is fantastic, thanks. Much cleaner than expanding my own vars and formatting a string.

Answer (score 1):

It would be cleaner and less error prone to format the string using `printf`

```
PET='dog'
NAME='sam'
toy1="t1"
toy2="t2"
toy3="t3"

jq_args=$(printf '.pets."%s" += {PetInfo: {name: "%s"}, toys: ["%s-postfix", "%s-postfix", "%s-postfix"]}}' "${PET}" "${NAME}" "${toy1}" "${toy2}" "${toy3}")
echo "$jq_args"
```

Result:

```
.pets."dog" += {PetInfo: {name: "sam"}, toys: ["t1-postfix", "t2-postfix", "t3-postfix"]}
```

Additionally, redundant quoting could be avoided by quoting the arg on this command

```
cat myfile.json | jq "$jq_args"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Fix your jq code by removing extra `}` at end
2. Fix bash jq call:

   Add cotes `"..."` around your `$jq_args`

   so don't use singles `'...'` in your `jq_args` definition
3. Use `printf` with `-v` option to define `jq_args`:

   `printf -v jq_args "...format..." value1 value2 ...`

So your code became:

```sh
PET="some-new-pet"
NAME="my-brand-new-pet"
toy1="toy1"
toy2="toy2"
toy3="toy3"
format='.pets."%s" += {PetInfo: {name: "%s"}, toys: ["%s", "%s", "%s"]}'
printf -v jq_args "${format}" "${PET}" "${NAME}" "${toy1}" "${toy2}" "${toy3}"
cat myfile.json | jq "$jq_args"
```

Output:

```
{
  "pets": {
    "some-new-pet": {
      "PetInfo": {
        "name": "my-brand-new-pet"
      },
      "toys": [
        "toy1",
        "toy2",
        "toy3"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Notes:

- When you define your format, you put it into simple cotes `'...'`. It's really better to format JSON (or XML) without back-slashes (`\\`) before each double cotes (`"`)
- Use `printf -v variable_name`. It's more readable than `var_name=$(printf ...)`

Comment: Generating code _even with `printf -v`_ is worse practice than using a language's own facilities; `jq --arg` or exporting variables to the environment and using `env` avoids potential injection attacks.

Comment: (that said, `printf -v` is not just more readable than a command substitution, it's also faster to run; so if one _is_ going to use printf, you're definitely showing the right way to do it).

Answer (score 1):

By constructing the jq filter ("code") using outer bash variables ("data") you may run into escaping issues, which could eventually break or even divert your filter. (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)

Instead, use mechanisms by jq to introduce external data through variables (parameter `--arg`):

```
jq --arg pet "${PET}" \
  --arg name "${NAME}" \
  --arg toy1 "${toy1}-postfix" \
  --arg toy2 "${toy2}-postfix" \
  --arg toy3 "${toy3}-postfix" \
  '
    
    .pets[$pet] += {PetInfo: {$name, toys: [$toy1,$toy2,$toy3]}}
    
  ' myfile.json
```

If you have an unknown number of variables to include, check out jq's `--args` parameter (note the additional `s`)

Comment: Weeble has essentially the same answer but was faster a couple of minutes.

Comment: Yeah, thanks either way though, this is great and I'm sure will help others in the future.